# Converting values from Tensile Strength tester to newtons

Tags: stresses, measurements, instrumentation, force-measurement

I have a Tensile Strength tester from [TMI model 84-76](https://pdf.directindustry.com/pdf/testing-machines-inc/tensile-tester/55801-79661.html).

I am getting data from this machine over the serial port. I don't understand what the values are that it is streaming during the test. I do know the following values:

max value found is S1098. 111.935 was max newtons.

111.935 = max N value

25.00 = sample width

25.40 = sample length

A sample of the data stream is as follows:
`S1086.288;S1086.288;S1087.288;S1084.288;S1085.288;S1087.289;S1086.289;S1086.290;S1085.290;S1081.290;S1084.291;S1084.291;S1084.292;S1084.292`

The second number after the decimal is the progression number.

So, the machine calculated a max newton value of 111.935 newtons. I assume the numbers following the 'S' are a base number that can then be used to represent the force on a graph. The test speed is 280mm/min. I'm not an engineer by trade and work in a print shop so please try to be nice as I realize this question may be dumb but have run out of places to look. Any assistance to help me understand how to convert this would be greatly appreciated. I want to build my own graph using this output data.